# Including Backbone in Heroku server-side scripts in nodejs/socket.io app

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm developing a small app as practice using node.js, Backbone, and socket.io, and I've managed to get something working locally (foreman start correctly starts the app with no errors). However, when deploying to heroku, I'm getting issues because my models.js file (used by the client and the server) requires Backbone. I'm sure it's something simple to get it to find it, but I'm new to node and newer to Backbone.

In my main app.js file (served by node), I have the vars

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
_ = require('underscore')._;
```

I also have a models.js file which is required by app.js as follows:

```
var models = require('./public/js/models.js');
```

(this file is also required by the client). In models.js, I start with the code

```
var server = false;
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    server = true;
    Backbone = require('Backbone');
    _ = require('underscore');
}
```

And I think this is where it's getting stuck. Apologies if this isn't the correct information to provide (the whole project can be found at https://github.com/kevadsett/testHeroku). Any help would be very much appreciated, as it's frustrating to have gotten through all the learning and development only to be scuppered at the upload stage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue might be just that you're trying to import a nonexisting modules:

```
Backbone = require('./Backbone');
 _ = require('./underscore');
```

Try instead:

```
Backbone = require('backbone');
 _ = require('underscore');
```

I didn't test it with your application, but principally this should work.

Comment: Ah you are right @fencliff, but I had spotted that and updated the project on github before uploading my question but forgot to update the code in the post. Unforunately that doesn't seem to be the problem here. I've not got the answer yet, but this article: http://elegantcode.com/2011/02/04/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-commonjs-and-creating-custom-modules/ has helped reinforce my knowledge on such things.

Comment: Oh wow, this turned out to be that rogue upper-case B in 'Backbone'. Thanks for your help!